# How to delete a file ending in a dot in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

After installing Cygwin on Windows 7 and realizing I'm better of with using Linux on a different partition, I wanted to uninstall it. However, Cygwin has no uninstaller so I was left with the option of deleting the whole folder it was installed in – which I did.

The problem is that a single file remained, in the whole directory tree, named `README.` at  `C:\cygwin\usr\share\texmf-dist\doc\latex\hausarbeit-jura\README.`

I know Windows isn't supposed to allow files with names ending in `.`, but this one obviously got through, and I cannot delete it. When trying to do that, I get

> **Item Not Found**
>
> This is no longer located in `C:\cygwin\usr\share\texmf-dist\doc\latex\hausarbeit-jura`. Verify the item's location and try again.

When viewing the properties of the file (Right-click, Properties), Windows tells me that it has 0 bytes.   However, when viewing it in the explorer window, and clicking on it, the windows status bar thing tells me it has 517 bytes.

Any ideas on how to get rid of it?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, as I'm not sure what steps you've taken, but have you tried deleting it from the cli?

Comment: Yes, I do get the exact same error.

Comment: You can write a short program to unlink specifically that file.  That WILL work.

Comment: dupliciate: [How to delete a folder that name ended with a dot(“.”)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4075753/995714)

Comment: Why not simply use **wildcards**: `del README*`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Having tried all of these suggestions and more, I still couldn't delete the offending files.

What finally did it was to use the following syntax (in an elevated command prompt):

```
del "\\?\<full path to file>"
```

eg, to use the original example:

```
del "\\?\C:\cygwin\usr\share\texmf-dist\doc\latex\hausarbeit-jura."
```

Comment: I did this when the vbs script solution in the accepted answer did not work. The file is gone now :]

Comment: This **works**! Really awesome!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This works with `del` but [doesn't work with some other `cmd` builtins like `move` and `rename`](https://superuser.com/questions/1322618/fix-a-file-directory-that-says-refers-to-a-location-that-is-unavailable-fil/1322619#1322619).

Comment: Its 2019 and I can confirm this works - and seems to be the easiest solution to do. Unclear if it matters, but I ran it from a CMD started in administrator mode.  Thanks @micha

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev 7zip-FM (7zip file manager) worked for me to rename dot-ended file on Win10 x64. Quick and painless. This idea found by way of https://superuser.com/questions/1322618/fix-a-file-directory-that-says-refers-to-a-location-that-is-unavailable-fil/1322619#1322619

Answer (score 20):

What a really simple solution that I've found. It's the simplest and fastest and easiest way to achieve this. I am now laughing at how simple it is.

1. Install [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm)
2. Follow the Step by Step procedure from the pictures:
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]

I don't know if you can do it with 7zip, but WinRAR has it and you don't have to buy it, just install the trial and then uninstall it (or probably portables out there but I don't think they are legit i.e. they are possibly cracked.)

Comment: Great trick. The only thing that worked for me

Comment: 7zip works fine. Thx :-).

Comment: I really like it, because in my experience broken files are often result of using WinRar

Comment: Very nice one. Winrar created my files, it should be able to delete them

Comment: This worked even though my dir-end-in-dot contained a file with name-ending-with-dot so that _nothing_ else worked.  Not even delete-on-reboot.  Woohoo!

Comment: 7-zip worked for me

Comment: Upvoted. Lovely example of thinking out of the box :)

Comment: Winrar seems to be able to just rename the file in its browser

Comment: Confirmed with 7ZIP under Windows 10. ... 7ZIP and WinRar beat the command line, unbelievable.

Comment: @Avatar glad that it helped you. So please mind upvoting me! Dont hesitate!

Answer (score 6):

Open an elevated command prompt and type in the following commands, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each one:

```
cd C:\cygwin\usr\share\texmf-dist\doc\latex\hausarbeit-jura\

del *.*

Y

cd c:\

rmdir /s /q C:\cygwin\usr\share\texmf-dist\doc\latex\hausarbeit-jura\

rmdir /s /q C:\cygwin\usr\share\texmf-dist\doc\latex\

rmdir /s /q C:\cygwin\usr\share\texmf-dist\doc\

rmdir /s /q C:\cygwin\usr\share\texmf-dist\

rmdir /s /q C:\cygwin\usr\share\

rmdir /s /q C:\cygwin\usr\

rmdir /s /q C:\cygwin\
```

Comment: I guess `del *.*` would have sufficed as an aswer...

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is to open a Windows Command Prompt window and use the **`rd`** command with the **`/S /Q`** options. You might have to open the Command Prompt as an **administrator** for this to work.

1. Click the **`Start Button (Orb)`** and locate the link to open the Command Prompt. If you don't see it, you might have to search for it by typing **`command`** or **`cmd.exe`** in the search box at the bottom.
2. Right click on the **`command`** or **`cmd.exe`** link and select **`Run as administrator`**, then click **`Yes`** if prompted to allow it.
3. In the Command Prompt window, type the command **(don't press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key yet):**
    **`rd /S /Q "C:\Cygwin"`**
4. This command will delete all the files and folders inside the specified folder without prompting, so be sure to double and triple check check that you have specified the correct folder.
5. If you want to be prompted to delete the files and sub-folders, type the command without the **`/Q`** like this:
    **`rd /S "C:\Cygwin"`**
6. When you are sure you have typed the command correctly, press the <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> key.

The **`Cygwin`** folder, and all the files and sub-folders within it will be deleted.

Here is the syntax for the **`rd`** command:

```
C:\>rd /?
Removes (deletes) a directory.

RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path

    /S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
            in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
            tree.

    /Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S
```

If there are 
**`System`, `Hidden,`** or **`Read-only`** files or folders that cause the **`rd`** command to fail, use the **`attrib`** command with the **`/S /D`** options like this:

**`attrib -S -H -R "C:\Cygwin\*.*" /S`**

to remove those attributes from the files and sub-folders, then re-try the **`rd`** command.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short VBScript file to do what you need.

```
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
obj.DeleteFile("C:\cygwin\usr\share\texmf-dist\doc\latex\hausarbeit-jura\README.")
```

This should bypass the issue you're having with the del command and windows explorer.  Just save that text as whatever.vbs and double click it.

If the file is flagged as read-only then you'll need to add a bit to that code, let me know.

Comment: I managed to delete the file in cli using DEL \*.\* (DEL README. wouldn't work).
However the folder still couldn't be deleted. Your script, adjusted for folders, did the trick. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Use bash rm command from Ubuntu on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was pretty easy. I have a dual-boot system with Linux, so I just booted into Linux, navigated to the file and deleted it. I'm sure you could do the same with a live CD.

Answer (score 1):

I had an image that has no extension by the name `cropped_image_new1597487825.`

Just open the elevated Command Prompt,

Type `dir /x` to obtain the 8.3 formatted filenames.

Delete the file using the 8.3 filenames, e.g. '`del CROPPE~2`'

Here is a working example:

```
C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proj_ci\uploads\profile_pic>del cropped_image_new1597487825.
Could Not Find C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proj_ci\uploads\profile_pic\cropped_image_new1597487825.

C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proj_ci\uploads\profile_pic>dir /x
 Volume in drive C is Windows 7
 Volume Serial Number is 6616-BD66

 Directory of C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proj_ci\uploads\profile_pic

05-11-2018  12:09    <DIR>                       .
05-11-2018  12:09    <DIR>                       ..
05-11-2018  12:06                 0 CROPPE~2     cropped_image_new1597487825.
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   6,169,853,952 bytes free


C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proj_ci\uploads\profile_pic>del CROPPE~2

C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proj_ci\uploads\profile_pic>dir /x
 Volume in drive C is Windows 7
 Volume Serial Number is 6616-BD66

 Directory of C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proj_ci\uploads\profile_pic

31-01-2019  14:58    <DIR>                       .
31-01-2019  14:58    <DIR>                       ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   6,169,702,400 bytes free
```