# How to delete an "a." file

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems

I created a text file with a wrong name called "a." on my Desktop and now I cannot moved, rename, nor delete it.
I already restarted many times, and the file is still there "unlinked".

I am working on windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64bits.

Is this another glitch yet to fix, as the famous c:/con/con on win98 that MS miserably failed to fix yet to these days?

[image]

Comment: Can you open the file? Have you tried deleting it using Command Prompt? Did you run `chkdsk` yet?

Comment: Hello @DanielB ,  
- I cannot open the file, 
- I cannot delete it using cmd: "del /f a.
- I ran the chkdsk and still there

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/494959/how-to-delete-a-file-ending-in-a-dot-in-windows-7

Comment: @Chris.C that solved the problem, Please somebody close this question