# Fix a file/directory that says "refers to a location that is unavailable" / "file not found" when trying to open it

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I've got a bunch of folders that upon trying to browse into them, say `"<directory> refers to a location that is unavailable"`. In [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), I see that the actual error code is `NAME_NOT_FOUND` -- but they are present.

- `chkdsk` finds no errors in the filesystem.
- Neither are they junctions or symbolic links (checked by installing the [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html))

I've noticed that the names have a common trait:

- they all have a dot at the end
- in the past, I experienced the same with file/directories with broken names like in the picture:

[image: broken folder names. source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/fnew-folder-refers-to-a-location-that-is/fd41d220-8183-4e19-9250-356dc1d66656]

**What's happening here and how do I fix this?**

[How to delete a file ending in a dot in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/494959/how-to-delete-a-file-ending-in-a-dot-in-windows-7) offers ways to *delete* it, but that's not acceptable 'cuz I need the contents.

- Unlike `del` suggested in that question, `rename "<directory>" "<smth else>"` produces the same `"File not found"`.
- Neither `\\?\<path>` works (same error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows API "preprocesses" paths before passing them to the kernel. The documentation on this is sketchy: [instead, MSDN lists just the net limitations.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) In particular:

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not.

[The Unicode I/O APIs that lift the `MAX_PATH` limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) seem to skip that preprocessing as well.

---

So, there are two ways of fixing:

- Use a program that uses the Unicode I/O API under the hood. Options include:

  - Cygwin utilities:

    - `mv <bogus_name> <new_name>`
  - [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](https://superuser.com/a/494960/106224)
  - [Some archivers like WinRAR/7-Zip](https://superuser.com/a/961603/106224) (their GUI may allow to do renames on regular files/dirs)
- Use the 8.3 name to access the file/dir:

  ```
  >dir /x
  <...>
  <DIR>          58B0~1       Для П.П.

  >rename 58B0~1 new_name
  ```

---

Using the "native path" -- `\\?\<full path>` -- doesn't help here because for some `cmd` builtins  -- at least, `dir` and `rename` -- these paths are still subject for the preprocessing:

```
>dir "\\?\C:\Users\Me\Для П.П."
<...>
 Directory of \\?\C:\Users\Me\Для П.П

File Not Found
```

(note the missing end dot in the output).

Comment: 7zip-FM (7zip file manager) worked for me to rename dot-ended file on Win10 x64. Quick and painless.