# Strange Undeletable Folder

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

Not sure if I have malware or not, but I discovered this folder as I was working on my website:
[image]

Seems pretty normal, right? Well, when I tried to delete it, it was apparently symlinked to the actual "sergix.net" folder in the same directory. Ok, whatever, I'll just delete the symlink. But then it gave a message as if it was deleting the symlinked folder; strange. I backed up the real folder and deleted it from the directory. However, now when I try and delete whatever this crap is, it just says how the "sergix.net" I moved doesn't exist:
[image]

But in cmd, it reports as a directory:
[image]

And when I try to delete, it just says "not" found, most likely because the folder it's apparently linked to doesn't exist:
[image]

Also, rmdir on this folder removes it's symlinked folder when it exists.

It's also worth noting that it displays this as `<DIR>` and not `<SYMLINK>`.

So at this point, I've also tried Unlocker, rebooting, and a bunch of other things. I also don't know what made this file or anything; I did scan for malware but all it found was a small Trojan that has been deleted.

Also, ATTRIB reports it not finding the file.

Any advice?

Comment: Try `dir /X` to display the old DOS-formatted short names for files. In my testing, most of the commands just ignore the `.` at the end, so it is trying to delete `sergix.net` instead of `sergix.net.`. [This Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/494959/how-to-delete-a-file-ending-in-a-dot-in-windows-7) may also be helpful.

Comment: Ah, ok. It does display `SERGIX~1`, however when I attempt to delete it it still is symlinking to the other directory; neither `del` or `rmdir` seem to work still.

Comment: It seems, for some odd reason, that of all things 7-Zip was able to at least move it, I found out after reading that Q&A. I'll see if I can delete it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I never considered it being that the folder name ended in a `.`; therefore, [if you use 7-Zip or WinRar, you can pack it into a ZIP while selecting the option to delete the original folder.](https://superuser.com/questions/494959/how-to-delete-a-file-ending-in-a-dot-in-windows-7) The only thing I'm still confused on is the Symlink aspect, but hey, it works.

Credit goes to @Worthwelle!