# An application attempted to save a file with a ':' in it, now the file is not deletable

Tags: windows-10

I used an application that creates files automatically which attempted to save a file with a ':' character on it on a Windows 10 system.  The colon is clearly not an allowed character - but somehow the application succeeded in creating a file of size zero bytes, with the name truncated from the colon onwards.

For example, if the file was named "My File : A history", the zero-byte file that was created was called "My File ".  I have three such files and am unable to delete them.

Using file explorer, I get a message box that says "This is no longer located in .  Verify the item's location and try again."

Using the command prompt to try and 'del' the file, I get an error that states "Could not find "

I get the same errors when moving them.

The files aren't causing any issues, but I'd like to delete them rather than have these be permanent fixtures of this directory.

Comment: Another: [How to delete (invalid) files with colon in their name under Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/165395/432690)

Comment: Agreed, recommend close as duplicate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions in this question:  This appears related... [How to delete a file ending in a dot in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/494959/how-to-delete-a-file-ending-in-a-dot-in-windows-7)

worked for me.